# Is iBooks on my iPad deleting local content?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, ibook

I used iBooks on the iPad to read pdf. Sometime I am looking forward to reading something offline (e.g. flight) just to realized that the local file is not there anymore. Is it some sort of iCloud sync gone wrong?

Comment: If you're using iCloud to sync the pdf's (and reading location/info), I don't think the document is actually downloaded to your device.  I *think* it stays in iCloud so you can access it from all your devices.  If this isn't what you want, you can try disabling iBooks in iCloud.

Comment: that's annoying. i assumed it was a local copy of a cloud file (as dropbox or google cloud)

Comment: Dropbox and Google Cloud are backup solutions whereas iCloud is a syncing solution.  iCloud's purpose is to keep things in sync across devices so it makes sense when you think of it that way.

Comment: @fsb In the iPad all work the same way. The data is in the cloud - if you access a file on the iPad it is downloaded to cache. So if going off line attempt to read all the files whilst you have a connection - then offline you will be able tos ee them.

Comment: Thanks @Mark.  meto, were you reading the pdf file right before you went offline?  I'm thinking that if there was a delay then the file might not have been in cache anymore so you wouldn't be able to access it.

Comment: yes @fsb I read the pdf when I had internet. Then some time after that I was disconnected and couldn't access it anymore. Note that it's not a problem of local storage, as the iPad has 100GB+ free space

Comment: I did a quick search and this type of issue has been out there since iOS 10.  I'm not seeing any solution that would save these files locally on the iPad.

Comment: thanks, not sure if they are sloppy or this is just a feature...